# Vehicle tracking and direction processing

Tags: infrared, proximity-sensor, laser, radar

Im trying to find a good way for tracking vehicles. Its like counting all the vehicles (cars, motor cycle or any vehicles)through a point on the road. Also it needs to count like how many in total and in each direction. It should work well in Nights or in Rain or deosnt matter what ever the condition.

If we go for camera way, its having limitations in extreme darkness (IRs can helpful in some extend) or when a strong light into the lens. So thats just be OK for some demo purpose and not a foolproof solution.

IR transmitter arrays and receiver placed at 4-5 meters above the road at some arches or some sort of things can track. But then the same issue if a strong light and external IR interference. Also Im a very beginner in electronics. So with my very little knowledge I dont think IR is OK or it will work for 5-6 meters.

Next way I got into my mind microwave doppler radar (like HB100). But it can only detect movement at some area. Its not giving any direction or location specific info.

When googling I found another way implemented at some locations like pressure sensor arrays been setup on the road as two lines and based on some analysis it can track. But its not sounds to be a perfect solution.

So I thought about laser ([Laser Distance Measure Module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/40m-2mm-High-precision-laser-distance-sensors-Serial-port-output-range-finder-module-Suitable-for-obstacle/32600205470.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.10.MCn5Jn&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10152_10065_10151_10068_10307_10137_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_100031_10099_10338_10339_10103_10102_440_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051_10326_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10175_10111_10112_10113_10114_143_10037_10312_10313_10314_10317_10318_10078_10079_10077_10073-10317,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&btsid=abe0b42d-a703-42a9-9d87-5a04f4562fc8&algo_expid=d9dfef9e-55fa-4266-abbf-7439f9de2bb5-1&algo_pvid=d9dfef9e-55fa-4266-abbf-7439f9de2bb5)) but I have  a little worry about its response time and will it work perfectly for the situation.

So any ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: This is quite a broad question but if your programming is good enough a decent camera using something like OpenCV should be enough. Remember at night the vehicles should have lights on although you'll probably need to use some adaptive exposure control at night.

Comment: Yea.. Fortunately am from software field.. and some experience in DSP and Image processing.. But my trust over cameras are little less since its more externally alterable

Comment: Thats true.. everything is alterable.. But about cameras, I mean at daylight just a piece of mirror is enough to blind cameras. Thats why I thought about any alternatives rather than cameras..

Comment: Don't forget about the weather... Fog, rain, snow, smoke etc can all change the performance of any remote sensing techniques. The old and tried pneumatic tube method is probably still the best for any short term survey though I have seen them use cameras on poles at roundabouts lately.

Comment: This is also a pretty common requirement used by most road planning departments worldwide. I'm sure you can find something commercially available for this.

Comment: Here is a solution that may be acceptable for after market fitting.  Vandal and weather resistant. The search went to an Alibaba page but should give enough ideas to find a vendor web site. -  https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ROSIM-Wireless-Vehicle-Sensor-Detector-Traffic_60327258474.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the road then a pair of inductive loops in the road surface will do.

They will each act basically like a metal detector. And most cars have a half ton of metal in the engine bay and transmission box.

If you can't do that then a set of pneumatic tubes strung along the road surface is a decent alternative. As the car driver over them the pressure will increase momentarily and you can log that. They are prone to damage and need replacing regularly but the tubes themselves are cheap enough.

Comment: Thats sounds cool. But about the first method, if a long trailer over the loops, does that work well? I mean at the accuracy point of view will it be 100%. Also there should be lots of points in a row isnt it to track if more than 7 or 10 vehicles on each direction without any lane control??

Comment: @sforsandeep These methods do assume that traffic is going through lanes.

Comment: Yea.. thats a trouble.. There is no proper lane control.. Its for local village roads...

Comment: Well the tubes can be strung over the entire width of the road and when deployed in pairs can register direction and speed (and number of axles).

Comment: @ratchetfreak the issue with the all the way across tubes is always that of vehicles crossing in both directions at once. If this is for a low volume location that may not be an issue though. I doubt if 100% accuracy is even feasible though. Something as simple as a utility trailer can mess you your count.